# What's the easiest way to add a quote box to mediawiki?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, quotes

I installed mediawiki on my server as my personal knowledge base. Sometimes I copy some stuff from Web and paste to my wiki - such as tips & tricks from somebody's blog. How do I make the copied content appear in a box with border?

For example, the box at the end of this blog post looks pretty nice:
http://blog.dreamhost.com/2008/03/21/good-reminiscing-friday/

I could use the pre tag, but paragraphs in a pre tag won't wrap automatically.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 39):

I made a template in my wiki called Template:quote, which contains the following content:

```
<div style="background-color: #ddf5eb; border-style: dotted;">
{{{1}}}
</div>
```

Then I can use the template in a page, e.g.,

> {{quote|a little test}}

Works pretty well - Thanks!

Answer (score 25):

```
<blockquote style="background-color: lightgrey; border: solid thin grey;">
Det er jeg som kjenner hemmeligheten din. Ikke et pip, gutten min.
</blockquote>
```

The blockquotes are better than divs because they "explain" that the text is actually a blockqoute, and not "just-some-text". Also a blockquote will most likely be properly indented, and actually look like a blockqoute.

Comment: Can you explain why blockquote is better than div? Thanks!

Comment: I agree <blockquote> is the better choice, however this should be encapsulated in a template

Answer (score 21):

To combine the two mostly valid answers, you should use a [MediaWiki template](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplates) that itself utilizes a [blockquote](http://www.htmlquick.com/reference/tags/blockquote.html).

The content of the template:

```
<blockquote style="color: lightgrey; border: solid thin gray;">
    {{{1}}}
</blockquote>
```

Usage on your WIKI page (assuming you named the template "quote"):

```
{{ quote | The text you want to quote }}
```

Comment: Just to explain the #1 in the braces, it means the first variable of possible several. Example "The quick {{{1}}} fox {{{2}}}." Then, we can fill the template as {{quote|brown|jumps}}, which translates to "The quick brown fox jumps." ('quote' being the name of the template).

Answer (score 4):

Mediawiki supports the div tag.  Combine the div tag with some styles:

```
<div style="background-color: cyan; border-style: dashed;">
A bunch of text that will wrap.
</div>
```

You can play around with whatever css attributes you want, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 4):

I used the code from @steve k Changing light-grey to black and adding padding between the border and text. I found the light-grey nearly invisible and the text was directly adjacent to the border.

```
<blockquote style="
 color: black;
 border: solid thin gray;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 padding-left: 10px;
 ">
{{{1}}}
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `index.php?title=MediaWiki:Common.css` page for this purpose and set a CSS style for the `<blockquote/>` element there:

```
blockquote {
    background-color: #ddf5eb; 
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

In a similar fashion you can style `<pre/>` which is useful for code snippets etc. so that it wraps content:

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -pre-wrap; 
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap; 
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

For longer code snippets you may want to use `<syntaxhighlight/>` (or `<source/>`) element that comes with [SyntaxHighlight extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight). You can [`style`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SyntaxHighlight#style) it too.

Answer (score 0):

Set a width in the pre tag, and it will wrap.

```
<pre width="80%">
```